# Userscript in Chrome, Cross-Origin communication

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, greasemonkey, userscripts

Chrome has its own Greasemonkey, anyway it has many limit. One of them is that its xmlhttprequest doen't support Cross-Origin. So is there any way to make it works?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chrome now supports cross-domain requests via GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/chrome-extensions-now-with-more.html).

Here's [the documentation for Greasemonkey's (Firefox) `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).

Answer (score 1):

If you also want the script to be Opera-friendly, you still won't be able to use GM_xmlhttpRequest.  However, using YQL and jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var getCrossDomain = function (url, callback, maxage) {
        if (typeof (url) !== 'undefined') {
            var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '"') + '&diagnostics=false&format=xml&callback=?&_maxage=';
            if (typeof (maxage) === 'undefined') {
                yql += '10000'; // Value is in ms
            }
            $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
                if (typeof (callbackX) === 'function') {
                    callback(data.results[0]);
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Some code here to handle a failed request
            });
        }
    };
```

Read http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/ for info on the maxage parameter.